# Bad Performance of Buffer in Linux + Golang

Tags: memory, go, cpu-usage

I've got this code

```
package main
import (
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", Method)
    log.Printf("Server Started")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}

func Method(pResponse http.ResponseWriter, pRequest *http.Request) {
    timeInitial := time.Now()
    log.Printf(strconv.Itoa(timeInitial.Nanosecond()),     strconv.FormatFloat(time.Now().Sub(timeInitial).Seconds()*1000, 'f', 2, 64))
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(pRequest.Body)
    buf.Bytes() 
    log.Printf(strconv.Itoa(timeInitial.Nanosecond()), strconv.FormatFloat(time.Now().Sub(timeInitial).Seconds()*1000, 'f', 2, 64))

}
```

In this machine:

- Processor : 2 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory:  8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- OS: Yosemite version 10.10.5

The result is this:

```
2015/08/28 23:09:59 444255510%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 444255510%!(EXTRA string=0.06)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 472140004%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 472140004%!(EXTRA string=1.06)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 473322028%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 473322028%!(EXTRA string=0.01)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 473377991%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 473377991%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 483981504%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 483981504%!(EXTRA string=0.06)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 487652426%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 487652426%!(EXTRA string=0.07)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 488064359%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 488064359%!(EXTRA string=0.07)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 493007447%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 493007447%!(EXTRA string=0.36)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 506383690%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 506383690%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 516324968%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 516324968%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 516484292%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 516484292%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 526459027%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 526459027%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 526568984%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 526568984%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 526645341%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 526645341%!(EXTRA string=0.01)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 533764558%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 533764558%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 533872219%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 533872219%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 542355931%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 542355931%!(EXTRA string=0.04)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 549176497%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 549176497%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 559803436%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 559803436%!(EXTRA string=0.05)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 559913211%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 559913211%!(EXTRA string=0.01)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 579428530%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 579428530%!(EXTRA string=0.05)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 585453710%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 585453710%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 587231793%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 587231793%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 601407050%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 601407050%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 609160787%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 609160787%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 617953845%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 617953845%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 618042591%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 618042591%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 629055567%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 629055567%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 642409323%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 642409323%!(EXTRA string=0.02)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 668017861%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 668017861%!(EXTRA string=0.12)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 677003700%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 677003700%!(EXTRA string=0.06)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 692284984%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 692284984%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 705532147%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 705532147%!(EXTRA string=0.06)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 712790204%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 712790204%!(EXTRA string=0.12)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 737197885%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 737197885%!(EXTRA string=0.07)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 743503323%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 743503323%!(EXTRA string=0.14)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 745206360%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 745206360%!(EXTRA string=0.06)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 763185757%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 763185757%!(EXTRA string=0.55)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 769112727%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 769112727%!(EXTRA string=0.08)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 805816057%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 805816057%!(EXTRA string=0.12)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 809677378%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 809677378%!(EXTRA string=0.08)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 828063305%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 828063305%!(EXTRA string=0.12)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 828338407%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 828338407%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 835510888%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 835510888%!(EXTRA string=0.07)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 882626159%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 882626159%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 897746270%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 897746270%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 931674931%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 931674931%!(EXTRA string=0.03)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 936024259%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/28 23:09:59 936024259%!(EXTRA string=0.05)
```

In this other machine :

- vendor_id    : GenuineIntel

  - cpu family  : 6
  - model   : 63
  - model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz
- MemTotal:       65845252 kB
- OS : Linux  3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The result is this

```
2015/08/29 01:16:54 471552059%!(EXTRA string=15.81)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 480068871%!(EXTRA string=15.67)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 507398302%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 521398742%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 202533461%!(EXTRA string=2327.37)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 338831795%!(EXTRA string=1191.18)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 531039526%!(EXTRA string=1037.30)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 593472114%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 609973091%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 593472114%!(EXTRA string=16.54)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 609973091%!(EXTRA string=15.73)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 394071392%!(EXTRA string=1238.16)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 638164663%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 638164663%!(EXTRA string=15.53)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 667631670%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 675844627%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 675844627%!(EXTRA string=14.16)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 711898262%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 300566416%!(EXTRA string=424.26)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 711898262%!(EXTRA string=13.02)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 632385443%!(EXTRA string=1115.35)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 753118239%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 753118239%!(EXTRA string=14.15)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 767381818%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 801314950%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 767381818%!(EXTRA string=33.99)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 816438476%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 372179187%!(EXTRA string=2457.93)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 836926824%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 836926824%!(EXTRA string=51.60)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 889729894%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 890430388%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 891713727%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 732229063%!(EXTRA string=1163.04)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 332690466%!(EXTRA string=1571.52)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 904336456%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 926288167%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 384796519%!(EXTRA string=1549.14)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 941601994%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 431987970%!(EXTRA string=1516.20)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 888973901%!(EXTRA string=1082.22)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 977186277%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 977186277%!(EXTRA string=0.06)
2015/08/29 01:16:54 977367193%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 977367193%!(EXTRA string=56.33)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 46374447%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 46374447%!(EXTRA string=0.28)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 869929721%!(EXTRA string=1176.83)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 46916778%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 66407207%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 80231754%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 66407207%!(EXTRA string=13.88)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 80231754%!(EXTRA string=12.10)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 99556642%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 105395202%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 121157010%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 105395202%!(EXTRA string=15.83)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 121157010%!(EXTRA string=12.82)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 134107839%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 134107839%!(EXTRA string=15.98)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 162712352%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 162712352%!(EXTRA string=16.46)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 179288920%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 194490367%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 202206415%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 49113060%!(EXTRA string=1165.79)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 473214551%!(EXTRA string=1760.64)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 239858481%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 32855481%!(EXTRA string=1213.72)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 56811869%!(EXTRA string=1231.75)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 295414269%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 295491576%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 889729894%!(EXTRA string=423.76)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 891713727%!(EXTRA string=427.99)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 121465765%!(EXTRA string=1204.92)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 904336456%!(EXTRA string=428.21)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 121526643%!(EXTRA string=1233.79)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 310004280%!(EXTRA string=1051.71)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 858909173%!(EXTRA string=2502.90)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 367541741%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 367541741%!(EXTRA string=18.04)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 393589632%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 407450080%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 46916778%!(EXTRA string=378.70)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 896338456%!(EXTRA string=1529.38)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 431101598%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 431101598%!(EXTRA string=8.42)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 462833623%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 462833623%!(EXTRA string=13.67)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 484103852%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 492334586%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 492410130%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 492334586%!(EXTRA string=13.06)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 511300492%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 511300492%!(EXTRA string=19.36)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 537223305%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 544019226%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 544019226%!(EXTRA string=16.19)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 560322064%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 993395050%!(EXTRA string=1566.96)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 560322064%!(EXTRA string=39.26)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 599688803%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 179288920%!(EXTRA string=421.14)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 157717567%!(EXTRA string=1443.31)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 507398302%!(EXTRA string=1093.78)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 609900746%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 239858481%!(EXTRA string=370.10)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 609900746%!(EXTRA string=14.23)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 993465302%!(EXTRA string=1644.50)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 655129719%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 66651321%!(EXTRA string=1601.79)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 521398742%!(EXTRA string=1156.10)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 295491576%!(EXTRA string=382.10)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 295414269%!(EXTRA string=389.39)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 702701065%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 137363675%!(EXTRA string=1574.04)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 393589632%!(EXTRA string=339.33)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 667631670%!(EXTRA string=1071.18)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 407450080%!(EXTRA string=338.06)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 484103852%!(EXTRA string=293.32)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 786006965%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 801314950%!(EXTRA string=998.25)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 816438476%!(EXTRA string=1008.98)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 848323630%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 655129719%!(EXTRA string=225.32)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 900971628%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 702701065%!(EXTRA string=212.15)
2015/08/29 01:16:55 953092419%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 786006965%!(EXTRA string=225.37)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 848323630%!(EXTRA string=263.25)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 890430388%!(EXTRA string=1221.25)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 99556642%!(EXTRA string=1013.02)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 599688803%!(EXTRA string=513.94)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 900971628%!(EXTRA string=213.58)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 114683782%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 194490367%!(EXTRA string=926.51)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 941601994%!(EXTRA string=1179.50)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 202206415%!(EXTRA string=944.82)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 953092419%!(EXTRA string=201.68)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 280223380%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 926288167%!(EXTRA string=1373.12)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 114683782%!(EXTRA string=213.67)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 365730070%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 537223305%!(EXTRA string=882.31)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 272782462%!(EXTRA string=4147.48)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 632615696%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 634781232%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 280223380%!(EXTRA string=360.50)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 365730070%!(EXTRA string=275.11)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 492410130%!(EXTRA string=1354.29)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 632615696%!(EXTRA string=214.78)
2015/08/29 01:16:56 634781232%!(EXTRA string=219.21)
2015/08/29 01:16:57 65374683%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:57 65573396%!(EXTRA string=0.00)
2015/08/29 01:16:57 65374683%!(EXTRA string=300.96)
2015/08/29 01:16:57 53842402%!(EXTRA string=5317.02)
2015/08/29 01:16:57 65573396%!(EXTRA string=305.82)
2015/08/29 01:16:58 26171685%!(EXTRA string=10149.46)
```

The same code on different machines producing different results. The time in the results is in milliseconds, and as you can, see the Linux machine prints form 5 seconds to 10 seconds only doing the simple code that I show before, but on the mac machine this does not happen. Unfortunately my final product should be on Linux, so the time executing this code is affecting  the final result of a high-performance product. I don't what is the trouble with this code in Linux. I will appreciate any help; for the moment, I'm stuck.

How I tested the code:

With a load test I sent 100 threads for 1 minute with a simple strategy, a test delay  1 second and a Random 0.5 on SoapUI 5.2.0

The request is this:

```
{
   "Field1":{
      "Key1":"HHHHHH",
      "Key2":"[branch code]",
      "Key3":"HHHHHHtest"
   },
   "Field2":{
      "Key1":"HHH"
   },
   "Field3":{
      "Key1":[
         {
            "Value1":0,
            "Value2":"HHHHHHH",
            "Value3":"HHH"
         },
         {
            "Value1":0,
            "Value2":"HHHH",
            "Value3":"HH"
         },
         {
            "Value1":1,
            "Value2":"HHHHHHHHHHHHH",
            "Value3":""
         },
         {
            "Value1":1,
            "Value2":"HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH",
            "Value3":"1"
         },
         {
            "Value1":2,
            "Value2":"HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH",
            "Value3":"3"
         },
         {
            "Value1":2,
            "Value2":"HHHHHHHH",
            "Value3":"1"
         },
         {
            "Value1":1,
            "Value2":"HHHHHHHHHHHHH",
            "Value3":"4"
         },
         {
            "Value1":2,
            "Value2":"HHHHHHHHHHHH",
            "Value3":"BB"
         }
      ]
   },
   "Field4":{
      "key1":11111111,
      "key2":11111111
   },
   "Field5":{
      "key1":[
         {
            "Value1":1,
            "Value2":2
         },
         {
            "Value1":1,
            "Value2":2
         },
         {
            "Value1":[
               {
                  "Value2":5
               }
            ],
            "Value1":1,
            "Value2":2,
            "children3":1
         }
      ]
   },
   "Field6":"HHH_HHHH_HHHHHHHH_HHHH",
   "Field7":"HHHHHHHHHHHHHH_HHHHH",
   "Field8":"4.1",
   "Field9":"12312312"
}
```

Note: I know from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644139/from-io-reader-to-string-in-go) that the code is not the most efficient, but I was not able to find an efficient solution.

EDIT 1 : Run the code with GODEBUG=gctrace=1 and go version go1.4.2 linux/amd64

http://pastebin.com/jvV8wAz7

EDIT 2 : Run the code with GODEBUG=gctrace=1 and go version go1.5 linux/amd64

http://pastebin.com/sM8TVzXW

Comment: Are these both on Go 1.5? (Or both 1.4?) And is that really all the code running on the server? I'd try running with gctrace=1 to see if GC behavior is different between them.

Comment: As a minor thing--you want `log.Println` instead of `log.Printf` to avoid the `EXTRA` output you're getting.

Comment: Oh--if the test requests are all local to your Mac on the first test, but remote over the Internet on the second test, you could be measuring network delay, not computation. `ReadFrom(pRequest.Body)` will take as long as it takes for the request body to be transmitted. That's my best guess right now. You could use `top` or some tool to see if there is high CPU usage on the server.

Comment: @twotwotwo version server linux go1.3.3 linux/amd64 , version mac go version go1.4 darwin/amd64, the test are remote and are executed by ssh terminal , so that nothing is travelling over the internet all is execute in the server

Comment: OK -- I would run both tests under the same version, and I suggest 1.5, which [could improve responsiveness a lot if it's a GC issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684862/how-fast-is-the-go-1-5-gc-with-terabytes-of-ram). And I'd run them with [`GODEBUG=gctrace=1`](http://godoc.org/runtime) and add results to the question by editing.

Comment: If *SoapUI* pauses at the wrong time, that could also affect your timings. Java versions could also be a factor. You could try getting results with a different, non-Java-based load generator like https://github.com/rakyll/boom or `ab`, or see if odd timings remain if you copy to `ioutil.Discard` instead of a `bytes.Buffer`.