# Debugging with Delve: execute function

Tags: debugging, go, delve

I setup a breakpoint in my Go code with `runtime.Breakpoint()`, save the file (my editor, Atom with [go-plus installed](https://atom.io/packages/go-plus), runs `go install .` on save). Then I run Delve in terminal with `dlv debug`, and type `continue` after it starts.

When the breakpoint kicks in, I want to test a couple of things (basically to print reader's data [via a `bytes.Buffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9649061/55504)). But, I get the following error

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer): "1:5: expected 'EOF', found ':='"
```

and in general cannot do much more than print values.

Is it really not possible to do this sort of thing? I am used to Python's `pdb` where setting variables or calling functions is not a problem and I would expect Delve is capable of the same.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: dlv is a debugger, its not an interpreter. If you have a variable in your code, which contains the data. You can type `print(variableName)` and you will get that.

Comment: delve in go 1.11 supports functions as an experimental feature.  pdb is easier to implement as python isn't a fully compiled language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible yet. *Right now* (2018-NOV) work is [in progress](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/119#ref-commit-2925c03) on Delve, but unfinished.

Go runtime [was changed](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21678) recently to allow this kind of call. Delve have a [Github issue](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/119) tracking the progress of such feature, but is still experimental and incomplete.